# JPA Hibernate inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

Suppose I have an abstract super class for "games"

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseGame {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="baseGame")
    public List<CardList> decks;

    //... lots of other fields
}
```

where card list is:

```
@Entity
public class CardList{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="basegame_id", nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private BaseGame baseGame;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<BaseCard> cards;   

    //... lots of other fields
}
```

The issue arises at The many to many relationshup.
Suppose I have 5 games and one or two might get added every year manually, and they all have different fields + information.

Game A has a list of cardA extends BaseCard

```
@Entity
public class GameA extends BaseGame{

}

//somehow have the cardList in the BaseGame super class of this object
// actually use the cardA instead of just "BaseCard"

@Entity
public class CardA extends BaseCard{

}
```

game B has a list of cardB extends BaseCard

```
@Entity
public class GameB extends BaseGame{

}

//somehow have the cardList in the BaseGame super class of this object
// actually use the cardB instead of just "BaseCard"

@Entity
public class CardB extends BaseCard{

}
```

my question is is, since I'd really like to handle this neatly with one superclass "BaseCard" (Since they have lots of fields in common too)
Would I need multiple CardList classes for each game and move them from the superclass to the subclass?

What I really want to know is: Can I make or tell  Hibernate/JpA to "use"  a different subclass of BaseCard depending on the criteria?

In this case that criteria would be "the subclass of BaseGame"

Answer (score 0):

To make it short no you can't.

Every base class would need a List of the concrete Card class but you still can use inheritance and your abstract BaseGame class should have an abstract method getCards() that return the card.